# Map Reduce Line Frequency of Words

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am currently working on a Hadoop project in Java. My objective is to make a map reduce that counts the line frequency of every word. As in, not outputting the exact amount of times a word is counted in the input file, but just counting how many lines it occurs in. If a word occurs in a line more than once, it should only be counted once because we are only counting how many lines it occurs in. I have a basic map reduce working that I will post, but I am a little lost on how to only count the line frequency of words instead of the full word count. Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

MapWordCount

```
public class MapWordCount extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
      private Text wordToken = new Text();
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
      {
          StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "[_|$#0123456789<>\\^=\\[\\]\\*/\\\\,;,.\\-:()?!\"']"); //Dividing String into tokens
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens())
        {
          wordToken.set(tokens.nextToken());
          context.write(wordToken, new IntWritable(1));
        }
      }
    }
```

ReduceWordCount

```
public class ReduceWordCount extends Reducer <Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
      private IntWritable count = new IntWritable();
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
      {
        int valueSum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values)
        {
          valueSum += val.get();
        }
        count.set(valueSum);
        context.write(key, count);
      }
    }
```

Driver Code

```
public class WordCount {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] pathArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (pathArgs.length < 2)
        {
          System.err.println("MR Project Usage: wordcount <input-path> [...] <output-path>");
          System.exit(2);
        }
        Job wcJob = Job.getInstance(conf, "MapReduce WordCount");
        wcJob.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        wcJob.setMapperClass(MapWordCount.class);
        wcJob.setCombinerClass(ReduceWordCount.class);
        wcJob.setReducerClass(ReduceWordCount.class);
        wcJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        wcJob.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < pathArgs.length - 1; ++i)
        {
          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(wcJob, new Path(pathArgs[i]));
        }
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(wcJob, new Path(pathArgs[pathArgs.length - 1]));
        System.exit(wcJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You might be overthinking it, you simply need to sptil the file/document up into lines (not words) then process/map one line at a time and keep a running total of lines. A very simplistic approach (with pusdo code) might be something like `for(int i = 0; i < doucment.length; i++){if(yourLine.contains(yourWord)) wordCount++;}` Obviously you would use a word map for this and prune/ignore any duplicates on a line, but the same logic applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are surprisingly simple in this use case of Hadoop's MapReduce, because Hadoop tends to read the input documents line-by-line even with `FileInputFormat` being explicitly specified for the format of the input data of a MR job (this goes far beyond the scope of your question, but you can check out about map and file splits in Hadoop [here](https://knpcode.com/hadoop/mapreduce/input-split-in-hadoop-mapreduce/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9258134/5644037)).

Since each mapper instance is going to have a line as its input, the only thing you have to worry about is:

**1.** splitting the text into words (after cleaning them up from punctuation, loose spaces, turning all of them to lowercase, etc.),

**2.** getting rid of the duplicates to end up with just the unique words of said line,

**3.** and signing every unique word as key with `1` as value, classic WordCount style.

For *2.* you can use a `HashSet` which (as you'd expect) is a Java data structure that only keeps unique elements while ignoring duplicates, to load every token to it and then iterate it to write the key-value pairs and send them to the reducer instances.

This type of application can look like this (I changed the way you tokenize the text in the `Map` function because it didn't seem to split each word but just split between punctuation symbols):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class LineFreq
{
    public static class MapWordCount extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        private Text wordToken = new Text();
        private static final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            // dividing String into tokens
            String[] tokens = value.toString()
                                .replaceAll("\\d+", "")           // get rid of numbers...
                                .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", " ")    // get rid of punctuation...
                                .toLowerCase()                                      // turn every letter to lowercase...
                                .trim()                                             // trim the spaces...
                                .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
                                .split(" ");

            Set<String> word_set = new HashSet<String>();   // set to hold all of the unique words (WITHOUT DUPLICATES)

            // add words to word set
            for(String word : tokens)
                word_set.add(word);

            // write each unique word to have one occurrence in this particular line
            for(String word : word_set)
            {
                wordToken.set(word);
                context.write(wordToken, one);
            }

        }
    }

    public static class ReduceWordCount extends Reducer <Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        private IntWritable count = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            int valueSum = 0;

            for (IntWritable val : values)
              valueSum += val.get();

            count.set(valueSum);
            context.write(key, count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] pathArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

        if (pathArgs.length < 2)
        {
            System.err.println("MR Project Usage: wordcount <input-path> [...] <output-path>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Job wcJob = Job.getInstance(conf, "MapReduce WordCount");
        wcJob.setJarByClass(LineFreq.class);
        wcJob.setMapperClass(MapWordCount.class);
        wcJob.setCombinerClass(ReduceWordCount.class);
        wcJob.setReducerClass(ReduceWordCount.class);
        wcJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        wcJob.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < pathArgs.length - 1; ++i)
        {
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(wcJob, new Path(pathArgs[i]));
        }
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(wcJob, new Path(pathArgs[pathArgs.length - 1]));
        System.exit(wcJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

So we can test it out with the following document as input:

```
hello world! hello! how are you, world?
i am fine! world world world! hello to you too!
what a wonderful world!
amazing world i must say, indeed
```

And confirm that words frequency is indeed being computer line-wise with the following output:

[image]