# How data is divided into input splits in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Data is physically divided into blocks and logically divided into input splits.

My question is how this input splits are decided as number of mappers depends on number of input splits and who is responsible to divide data into input splits?

Comment: Some answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831507/how-does-hadoop-perform-input-splits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Hadoop perform input splits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831507/how-does-hadoop-perform-input-splits)

Comment: Also helpful is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291170/how-does-hadoop-process-records-split-across-block-boundaries